# streamlit st_aggrid not updating on values change

Tags: python, pandas, grid, streamlit

In this code you can choose an offset (1000, 2000, 3000) on which a pandas DataFrame is calculated.

Then the dataframe `df`, the corresponding `st_aggrid` and the description of `st_aggrid` are visualised on a web page:

```py
import streamlit as st
from st_aggrid import *
import pandas as pd

offset = int(st.selectbox("Offset", ["1000", "2000", "3000"]))

df = pd.DataFrame({"col1":[10,11,12,13], "col2":[20,21,22,23]}) + offset

st.subheader("DataFrame")
st.dataframe(df)

st.subheader("st_aggrid")
ag1 = AgGrid(df,
       # key="unique_key",  # <=============== remove the comment here
       update_mode=GridUpdateMode.VALUE_CHANGED
)

st.subheader("st_aggrid description")
st.write(ag1)
```

It works.

**It doesn't update `st_aggrid` anymore** as soon as a `key` argument is defined.

With `key`, the dataframe and the description are updated, the `st_aggrid` no more.

Am I missing something or could it be a bug?

Comment: There is an interesting [writing](https://pablocfonseca-streamlit-aggrid-examples-example-jyosi3.streamlit.app/) that could explain this behavior. Press "Controling Ag-Grid redraw".

Comment: @ferdy, thank you!  `reload_data` does work indeed. I completely missed it: imho it is quite unintuitive, as `update_mode=GridUpdateMode.VALUE_CHANGED` should override it. Could you please put your comment as answer so I can upvote it?